# not in operator in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

there is 2 tables

```
table1
ID
1
2
4
6
7

TABLE2
2
4
6
```

i want those number from table1 which is not in table2 how i do this ?
i try this

```
select id from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t1.id not in (select id from table2)
```

but this is not working

Comment: You don't have to do a `join` here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL NOT IN Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187780/sql-not-in-clause)

Comment: then ? this question is different from duplicate question

Comment: _but this is not working_ -> What result did you get? Or perhaps an error? Please show your output or your error message.

Comment: i got only heading "ID"

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Conceptually, we select all rows from table1 and for each row we attempt to find a row in table2 with the same value for the id column. If there is no such row, we just leave the table2 portion of our result empty for that row. Then we constrain our selection by picking only those rows in the result where the matching row does not exist. Finally, We ignore all fields from our result except for the id column (the one we are sure that exists, from table1).

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
select id from table1 t1 where t1.id not in (select t2.id from table2 t2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to join the two tables in this case. You could just do

```
  select id from table1 A where A.id not in (select B.id from table2 B);
```

You could also just simply use the sql set difference EXCEPT operator to achieve this

```
  (select id from table1) except (select id from table2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`

```
select id from table1 t1
where t1.id not in (select id from table2) 


select id from table1 t1
where not exists (select id from table2 where id = t1.id)
```